# Amazon MWS receiving MalformedInput on GetMyFeesEstimate

Tags: c#, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to access Amazon MWS API from my .Net application, using Products API Section Client Library - C# (https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/cSharp.html/138-8219342-3408216)

Everything works fine, except for `GetMyFeesEstimate` calls.
I use this method from example:

```
public GetMyFeesEstimateResponse InvokeGetMyFeesEstimate()
    {
        // Create a request.
        GetMyFeesEstimateRequest request = new GetMyFeesEstimateRequest();
        string sellerId = "example";
        request.SellerId = sellerId;
        string mwsAuthToken = "example";
        request.MWSAuthToken = mwsAuthToken;
        FeesEstimateRequestList feesEstimateRequestList = new FeesEstimateRequestList();
        request.FeesEstimateRequestList = feesEstimateRequestList;
        return this.client.GetMyFeesEstimate(request);
    }
```

And I add item to `FeesEstimateRequestList` like this:

```
feesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.Add(new FeesEstimateRequest
        {
            MarketplaceId = marketplaceId,
            IdType = "ASIN",
            IdValue = "B0078LENZC",
            PriceToEstimateFees = new PriceToEstimateFees { ListingPrice = new MoneyType { Amount = 30.49M, CurrencyCode = "GBP" }, Shipping = new MoneyType { Amount = 3.5M, CurrencyCode = "GBP" }, Points = new Points { PointsNumber = 0 } },
            Identifier = "request_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            IsAmazonFulfilled = false
        });
```

But constantly get `MalformedInput` error with no message describing what is wrong:

```
<ErrorResponse
xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">  
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MalformedInput</Code>   
</Error>   
<RequestId>f79b9147-90d7-4ea2-b51c-d6c37c6a1bd0</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Have someone any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Hello, i have the same Error :( Do you have fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

Due to my OS regional settings, decimal separator in price had being set to **comma**, instead of **dot** when converting parameters to string.

I have to modify method putValue of MwsAQCall class like this:

```
private void putValue(object value) 
    {
        if (value==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (value is IMwsObject)
        {
            parameterPrefix.Append('.');
            (value as IMwsObject).WriteFragmentTo(this);
            return;
        }
        string name = parameterPrefix.ToString();
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            parameters.Add(name, MwsUtil.GetFormattedTimestamp((DateTime)value));
            return;
        }
        string valueStr = value.ToString();
        if (value is decimal)
        {
            valueStr = valueStr.Replace(",", ".");
        }
        if (valueStr==null || valueStr.Length==0) 
        {
            return;
        }
        if (value is bool)
        {
             valueStr = valueStr.ToLower();
        }
        parameters.Add(name, valueStr);
    }
```